# How can I increase the number of allowed values on an image field?

Tags: entities

I need to increase the allowed number of image uploads to 15. Is there anyway to do this in a module or other means without hacking core files as suggested here - http://drupal.org/node/680546#comment-4126378?

This is Drupal 7.

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 2):

You could also change the cardinality setting of your field instance without doing a direct query. The key function would be field_update_instance() and here is an example of how to modify your field: http://sivaji.drupalgardens.com/how-programmatically-change-field-instance-properties

Comment: @Tim Wooten, if you have the time this is definitely the best practice. While the UI is probably what people use 99% of the time, fields in D7 were built to be defined in code and for the UI to supplement this logic.

Comment: So far I've wasted around 6 hours looking for the answer so time is running out. I had a look at the code but it's not very helpful. I'm not sure where to call it from. Obviously a module but inside what function?

Comment: I assume that you only need to do this one time. Then, you can do it in hook_install() where "hook" is replaced with your module name, eg. my_module_install() http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_install/7

Comment: Joe, I'm not creating my own field. I'm using core's image field and simply want to have an option of choosing 15 instead of 1-10 or "unlimited". 10 is not enough but unlimited is too many. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change the cardinality of the field in field_config table:

```
UPDATE field_config SET cardinality = 15 WHERE field_name = 'field_my_field_name'
```

Afterwards, clear your cache.

Comment: might end up having to do this.

Comment: Please follow up when you figure it out.

Comment: I ran out of time on this one. Explained the issue to the client and he said just use 'Unlimited'. I'd rather have a good solution but don't have time to chase it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

With a simple form alter you can allow arbitrary high cardinality settings.
See [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33178/how-do-i-set-the-fixed-amount-of-values-to-11)

.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this fairly simply using hook_form_alter. Check out the code here:

https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/ydahi/2421885

```
/**
* Using hook_form_alter to change the field cardinality.
*/
function custom_number_of_values_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
// Set the range using the user supplied values.
$lowerlimit = variable_get('custom_number_of_values_minimum', '1');
$upperlimit = variable_get('custom_number_of_values_maximum', '20');
$range = drupal_map_assoc(range($lowerlimit, $upperlimit));
$new_options = array(FIELD_CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED => t('Unlimited')) + $range;
// Change the options.
$form['field']['cardinality']['#options'] = $new_options;
}
```